# USB From PC to TV

Tags: usb, tv

I was wondering if any have an idea of how to use you pc as an external HDD for the tv, so that you get full access to the HDD from the tv, only using USB browsering.

I know that this is a crazy idea, but it would help me a lot because my TV is a Phillips and the most DLNA servers that i found is not stable all the time.

If you have any idea please tell me, then i will try that out.

Comment: Why USB only? You can get a media player (via ethernet) which does this and is stable. Either way, this is not a PC question (IMO), it's a TV question.

Comment: Probably impossible, PC is a USB host, not USB client like external HDDs.

Comment: Just turn your computer into a DLNA server. The external HDDs that support DLNA run a small Linux kernel.  You would have to use LAN and not USB to do this of course.  Your PC's USB ports are not design to be a client.

Comment: Is there not any way to make one of you usb ports work as usb-client?

I know that you kan use DLNA, but i wold like to be able to do it over usb if possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB used a master-slave setup.

Usually one has a host which acts as a master, and a slave device with a totally different role. Those two are not interchangeable. USB even uses clearly distinct connectors to indicate the kind of device and to make sure that you connect a master to a slave, and not two slaves or two masters.

[image: USB connectors (regular size)]

To use your PC as a storage device you would either need an USB controller which acts as a slave, or a controller which can be used both as a master or as a slave.

These are **not** common. Usually you only find them in a few portable devices (such as smartphones) and there it is called [USB on the Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go). No regular PC that I know off supports this feature.

Comment: Is accept you answer for now, but I hope that someone have a way to do it..

I have a USB -> USB so there should be something that I can use it for.