# Is there a way to connect non-smart TV to PC via USB?

Tags: networking, usb, tv

I have a non-smart TV with USB features, I can plug a USB drive with media like video, music, etc.

But it's kind of hassle to remove and replug everytime I want to fill new data into the USB drive and I'm afraid the USB port will break if I constantly remove and replug.

Is there a way for my TV to access my PC drive? I'm looking for device similar to Chromecast except it's using USB instead of HDMI. Does it exist?

The reason I want a USB device instead of HDMI is that I've tried few HDMI device and the video quality is just not as good compared to play the video directly from USB.

Comment: It might be possible but consider this, you are trying to do things backwards. USB is designed for data, HDMI for video & sound. If your TV doesn't have a media player built-in (aka non-smart TV) then you won't be able to play on your PC and stream audio&video over USB, as far as I know.

Comment: @posdef: My TV have a media player built-in, but no ethernet port. I've tried watching video by connecting my PC to TV through HDMI. Playing uncompressed FullHD video doesn't look as good compared to playing with built-in media player.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serve up PC hard drive as USB mass storage](http://superuser.com/questions/41841/serve-up-pc-hard-drive-as-usb-mass-storage)

Comment: Also: [USB From PC to TV](http://superuser.com/questions/637676/usb-from-pc-to-tv?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The Sandisk Connect might be a solution.  It's a USB flash drive that has WiFi connectivity and after some searching it appears that you can transfer files over USB and WiFi.  You'd still have to manually transfer the files via web browser and I have not tried this myself, so you may want to do some more research but it should solve your worry of constantly unplugging it to add files.

https://www.sandisk.com/home/mobile-device-storage/connect-wireless-stick

Answer (score 0):

Your TV can probably only read USB mass storage devices, so the answer is **NO**, unless your PC can expose its disks via USB. It needs to have a USB-B or USB-OTG port to do so. This is uncommon (I have never seen it on x86 PCs) but not technically impossible. For example I own an ARM computer running Linux with an USB OTG, and it has an option to expose any block device, including HDD, as USB mass storage via that port.